# Network transfer from host to VM very slow - VMWare Server & Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, vmware-server

Im trying to transfer a file from a Windows 7 host running VMWare Server to a Windows 2003 server VM, and it's painfully slow.

I've tried adding/adjusting registry keys and settings found on KB articles, and still nothing.

Ive tried this:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/898468
- http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1619

Vmware tools are installed.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Are the VMs all on teh same host and if so, on the same hard drive

Comment: Its one VM, on the same host machine, but on a separate drive

Comment: Are there any other VMs on the host? If so, are they experiencing similar performance?

Comment: What kind of NIC? If it is a RealTek, then this is a known issue for VMWare Server v2 and Workstation v7 (for some ReakTek cards). I searched the VMWare forums and KB site and tried their suggestions, such as disabling TCP Offload, IPv4 Checksum, etc. Unfortunately, I could never find a working solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this on your Windows 7 host:

1. open command line
2. netsh int IP set global taskoffload=disabled
3. disable your NIC
4. enable your NIC